# Deploying Ruby on Rails Website with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried looking all over the web and nothing really helps. Everyone seems to be using an Mac or skips some knowledge about what SSH is and how to use it.

Is there an tutorial site or video out there for someone like me to full upload my first rails website?

Basically goes from zero to upload.

I'm using RubyMine to program my rails and I prefer to upload to the the cheapest site. Such as digitalocean since it is $5/mo.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), they have good documentations and I've deployed around 5 rails apps via them while using Windows. They also have a free tier which works quite well for pet projects.

This [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) covers from setup to deployment, and even scaling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tutorials of developing and deploying rails website, I recommend [railsturorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/), an online ebook of learning to develop rails website. It shows how to deploy a rails website in [charpter 1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning), using [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) as website host.

BTW, [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is a good platform which can host rails website for free.